# how to diplay record using ajax in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I am using diplay function for the display record from database but it is not working. it give me error of undefined . i don't know what is the problem .

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   function display(){
   var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "insert.aspx?opr=display", false);
   xmlhttp.send(null);
                       
   document.getElementById("ddd1").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responeText;

  }
```

on other page

```
          if(opr=="display")
            {

            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmdd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmdd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmdd.CommandText = "select * FROM [ajaxtest].[dbo].[table2]";
            cmdd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdd);
            da.Fill(dt);
            Response.Write("<table border='1'>");
            Response.Write("<tr>")
            Response.Write("<td>");Response.Write("name");Response.Write("</td>");
            Response.Write("<td>"); Response.Write("city"); Response.Write("</td>");
          
            Response.Write("</tr>");


            foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                Response.Write("<tr>");
              
                Response.Write("<td>"); Response.Write(dr["name"].ToString()); Response.Write("</td>");
                Response.Write("<td>"); Response.Write(dr["city"].ToString()); Response.Write("</td>");
                Response.Write("</tr>");

            }


            Response.Write("</table>");
            con.Close();
        }
```

it is giving me error of " Undefined"

Comment: Have you check by putting break point to see if your C# code execute or not?

Comment: Yes in    Response.Write(dr["name"].ToString());
                 Response.Write(dr["city"].ToString());  lines it is fetching values but not showing

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to add onreadystatechange callback to make sure request completes before updating html as following and check whether it works or not:

```
function display(){
   var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
       document.getElementById("ddd1").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responeText;
    }
   };
   xmlhttp.open("GET", "insert.aspx?opr=display", false);
   xmlhttp.send(null);
  }
```

Comment: Still giving me Undefined Error

Comment: add Response.End(); after Response.Write("</table>"); and con.Close(); before Response.Write("</table>");